# Run-time error '52' (Bad file name or number) - Excel VBA createFolder - Mircosoft teams drive

Tags: excel, vba

Iam developing a vba marco-script for a customer which downloads zip file from github, and unpack the zip folder to a folder.

The script will create a folder ´pb´ if it doesnt exist already - and if the folder already exist it will delete the folder and create a new.

It works properly on my own pc, but the customer is getting this error as shown on screenshot.

The path on client's computer is following:

> C:\Users\Nicol\xxx\xxx - Carina og Nicolas - Carina og Nicolas\Analyseværktøjer\Rådgivningsværktøj

And the client is using mircosoft teams drive, but it didnt work neither on his own desktop folder. So i dont know what cause it.

I cant figure out how to solve this.

[[image: screenshot1]

Here is full source code of the marco.

```
Option Explicit

Function versionIsOutdated(strDir As String, strPath As String)
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FileToRead As Variant
Dim TextString As String

Dim path As String

path = strPath & strDir

If FSO.FolderExists(path) Then
' exist, lookup versionNumber
        Dim FileUrl As String
        Dim objXmlHttpReq As Object
        Dim objStream As Object
        Dim strResult
        
        FileUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Securelife-A-S/pb_integration/main/version.txt"
        
        Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", FileUrl, False
        objXmlHttpReq.send
        strResult = objXmlHttpReq.responseText
        
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set FileToRead = FSO.OpenTextFile(path & "\pb_integration-main\version.txt", ForReading) 'add here the path of your text file
        TextString = FileToRead.ReadAll
        FileToRead.Close
        Debug.Print (TextString)
        Debug.Print (strResult)
        Dim compResult As Integer
        
        If StrComp(TextString, strResult) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print ("Version is up to date")
        versionIsOutdated = False
        Else
        versionIsOutdated = True
        Debug.Print ("Version is outdated")
        End If
Else
versionIsOutdated = True
Debug.Print ("Folder is not downloaded yet")
End If

End Function
Function MkDir(strDir As String, strPath As String)

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim path As String

path = strPath & strDir

If FSO.FolderExists(path) Then
' exist, so delete the folder
          FSO.DeleteFolder path, True
          Debug.Print "Deleting folder"
End If

If Not FSO.FolderExists(path) Then

' doesn't exist, so create the folder
          FSO.CreateFolder path
          Debug.Print "Creating folder"
End If

End Function


Function downloadAndUnzip()


Dim FileUrl As String
Dim objXmlHttpReq As Object
Dim objStream As Object
Dim strResult

FileUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Securelife-A-S/pb_integration/main/version.txt"

Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", FileUrl, False
objXmlHttpReq.send
strResult = objXmlHttpReq.responseText

Debug.Print (strResult)

FileUrl = "https://github.com/Securelife-A-S/pb_integration/archive/refs/heads/main.zip"

Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", FileUrl, False
objXmlHttpReq.send

If objXmlHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
     Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     objStream.Open
     objStream.Type = 1
     objStream.Write objXmlHttpReq.responseBody
     objStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "pb.zip", 2
     objStream.Close
End If


Debug.Print ("Download done")
     
Dim ShellApp As Object
'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ShellApp.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.path & "\pb").CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(ThisWorkbook.path & "\pb.zip").Items

Debug.Print ("Unpack done")
End Function

Function DeleteVBComponent()
Dim CompName As String
CompName = "Main"
'Disabling the alert message
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Ignore errors
On Error Resume Next


'Delete the component
Dim vbCom As Object
     
Set vbCom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents

vbCom.Remove VBComponent:= _
vbCom.Item(CompName)
On Error GoTo 0

'Enabling the alert message
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function

Function addBasFile()

Dim path As String
Dim objModule As Object

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\pb\pb_integration-main\Main.bas"
Set objModule = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import(path)
objModule.Name = "Main"


Debug.Print path

End Function

Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim asd As Boolean
asd = versionIsOutdated("pb", ThisWorkbook.path & "\")
If asd = True Then
    MsgBox "Der er kommet ny version - Downloading påbegyndt"
    Call MkDir("pb", ThisWorkbook.path & "\")
    Call downloadAndUnzip
    Call DeleteVBComponent
    Call addBasFile
    Application.Run ("Main.init")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ask your client if he uses one drive resp. sharepoint. If he does `ThisWorkbook.path` will return a URL which VBA and FSO cannot really deal with. In such a case I'd suggest to use a synced one drive / sharepoint and use the local file names. You still have to convert `ThisWorkbook.path` to a local file name.

Comment: @Storax

Thank you, i will test this and debug "ThisWorkbook.path" and figure out if it returns something else